# Vue.js route params data getting lost after the full page reload

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am passing a user id from the router-link using params to display the detail of the user in the profile page and i am getting all the required data and also is displayed correctly but as soon as i reload the page the $route.params.id changes into undefined and the data which were shown are gone to get the data i have to again navigate to the index page and revisit the link.

my index.vue page with the router-link is as follow

```
<h6 class="author">
    <router-link :to="{name: 'FrontProfile' , params: {
         id: post.user.id }}"
         tag="a" active-class="active">{{post.user.name}}
    </router-link>
</h6>
```

my profile page code is :

```
data(){
       return {
               id: this.$route.params.id,
               user: {},
               thoughts: {},
               }
        },
methods:{
         viewProfile() {
            axios.get('user_profile/' + this.id).then((response) => {
                this.user = response.data.user_data;
                this.thoughts = response.data.thoughts;
            }).catch(() => {

            });
        },
 watch:{
        '$route' : 'viewProfile'
    },
created() {
        this.viewProfile();
    }
```

What can I try to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem in CodePen? Other doubt, after reload page, the `id` is in URL?

Comment: Post your file of route too.

Comment: Other idea: Maybe there is a problem in event `created`, try to use the `mounted` event.

Comment: If this is happening when you refresh the browser on the profile url, then it sounds like it could be to do with how your catching the url server side, maybe the id is not getting passed through there.

Comment: @GabrielWillemann i will post the problem in codepen also as you asked.

Comment: i have done mounted and also created the computed property for id but i can't get the job done @GabrielWillemann well my route file is 

    {path: '/user_profile', component: Profile ,name: 'FrontProfile'},

since i am passing the id to a controller from where i am fetching the data so the id is being passed through a php route

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to put your id as a computed prop?
If you leave it in the component data, it will just update on create the component, and you can remove the watcher over $route, what is a higher operation than a computed property.

```html
data(){
  return {
    user: {},
    thoughts: {},
  }
},
methods:{
 viewProfile() {
    // You can use destructuring here over your response
    axios.get('user_profile/' + this.id).then(({ data: { user_data, thoughts } }) => {
        this.user = user_data;
        this.thoughts = thoughts;
    }).catch(() => {

    });
},
computed: {
  id() {
    return this.$route.params.id;
  }
},
// because of the vue lifecycle hooks, this should be a `mounted` hook intead of a `created`
mounted() {
  this.viewProfile();
}
```

Comment: I tried that too but the problem is not yet fixed mate. can't get the id after the refresh still.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the trouble mates i fixed the issue by changing some routes configurations. Really thankful for your efforts.There was a collision between my web routes and the vue routes which was solved.